# DrawerNavigator lag

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm updating an Expo app from react-navigation 1.5 to 3.0.9, I noticed a very annoying issue: the drawer is reaally laggy. The video is for the development mode, but I tried the release mode, little less laggy *but still a problem*. With react-navigation v1 I've never had this kind of problem.
This is the code

```
const CustomDrawer = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <ScrollView>
                <ImageBackground
                    source={require('./assets/images/menu.png')}
                    style={{width: '100%',
                        height: 140,
                        justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
                    <Image style={{resizeMode: "contain", width: 72, height: 72, marginLeft:10, marginTop:10}} source={require('./assets/images/icon.png')} />
                    <Text style={{ color: 'white', paddingLeft:10, paddingBottom:10, fontSize: 20 }}>
                        Title
                    </Text>
                </ImageBackground>
                <DrawerItems {...props} />
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

this is the demo
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QGL8UarKcqVmWzQzhmN2aWwDrH2qPBht